# How to refine the results of a breeze query on the server?

Tags: breeze

I have a requirement to **refine the results of an Breeze controller IQueryable *on the server*** before the results are returned to the client.

The client will be issuing projection queries to an IQueryable resource; the client query will potentially include a where clause and an order by clause.

After the query has been executed against the database (using Entity Framework), but before the results of the query are returned to the client I want to transform the results into xml or csv format.

For technical reasons I can't perform this transformation on the client.

In fact I suspect I might not even be able to return to the client the results of the query except for a (string) url. As an aside, this url would probably point to an MVC Action that returns a FileResult containing the csv or xml results of the query temporarily saved on the server.

Thanks
Christian

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a `.where(...)` on client, you can do `.withParameters(...)`. Then you can read those parameters in your Action method, manually apply whatever you need to apply, transform final data into specified format and return it. Your Action method won't be IQueryable<> anymore. All "refining" parameters will have to be sent in `.withParameters(...)` and you will have to do it all by yourself. Shouldn't be too hard if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks Dominictus for your response. It's definitely an option but I'm hoping for a more general solution whereby the client js defines its data requirements using the where, select and order by on the EntityQuery, and the server does the transformation on the *results* of these otherwise standard breeze queries.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, `.where` is executed after `return` statement therefore you will get only data from server as-is, no modifications. If you want modifications, you will have to write `.withParameters()`

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem! I'm guessing that the general solution that I'm looking for would be  to create an ActionFilter that runs after the breeze library code.

Comment: @Christian did you ever end up doing this? I'm trying to do something similar and save a csv from a query instead of returning the objects but ran into the same issue, where the filtering isn't done until after the controller returns the data.